# Why i can't get paymentId with PayPal Native-Checkout Android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-android-sdk

Hi i have mobile application using paypal sdk ,

i have create configure my application with paypal , all proccess going well but when the payment done i get only PayerId and OrderId ,

for PaymentId i got null ,

**the payment id very important for me because i'm sending it to my server to check if payment done proccess the server for client .**

this is my app config

```
         config = new CheckoutConfig(
            getApplication(),
            "APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID",
            Environment.SANDBOX,
            String.format("%s://paypalpay", "APPLICATION_ID"),
            CurrencyCode.USD,
            UserAction.PAY_NOW,
            new SettingsConfig(
                    true,
                    false
            )
    );
    PayPalCheckout.setConfig(config);


    payPalButton = findViewById(R.id.payPalButton);

    payPalButton.setup(
            new CreateOrder() {
                @Override
                public void create(@NotNull CreateOrderActions createOrderActions) {
                    ArrayList purchaseUnits = new ArrayList<>();
                    purchaseUnits.add(
                            new PurchaseUnit.Builder()
                                    .amount(
                                            new Amount.Builder()
                                                    .currencyCode(CurrencyCode.USD)
                                                    .value("10.00")
                                                    .build()
                                    )
                                    .build()
                    );
                    Order order = new Order(
                            OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                            new AppContext.Builder()
                                    .userAction(UserAction.PAY_NOW)
                                    .build(),
                            purchaseUnits
                    );
                    createOrderActions.create(order, (CreateOrderActions.OnOrderCreated) null);
                }
            },
            new OnApprove() {
                @Override
                public void onApprove(@NotNull Approval approval) {
                    approval.getOrderActions().capture(new OnCaptureComplete() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureComplete(@NotNull CaptureOrderResult result) {
                            Log.i("CaptureOrder", String.format("CaptureOrderResult: %s", result));
                            Log.i("CaptureOrder", String.format("CaptureOrderResult: %s", approval.getData().getOrderId()));
                            Log.i("CaptureOrder", String.format("CaptureOrderResult: %s", approval.getData().getPaymentId()));
                            Log.i("CaptureOrder", String.format("CaptureOrderResult: %s", approval.getData().getPayerId()));

                            

                        }


                    });



                }
            }

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution :

1. In the new PayPal `Native-Checkout` Android SDK, they don't provide `paymentId`; you can only get `PayerId` and `OrderId`
2. I use the `OrderId`; I send the `OrderId` to my server then. I use PayPal PHP SDK V2 to get the Order details response, which has `PaymentId` and all other payment information.

Comment: Do you mean `PuyerId`? Or did you mean e.g. `PayerId` or `BuyerId`?

Comment: PayerId, the unique id of the PayPal account sending the money. More useful for reference than the primary email since emails can be changed and moved between accounts

Comment: I mean i can't get PayementId

Answer (score 1):

It will not be in the `approval` object, it will be in the capture `result` since it is created after capture. You are already logging the `result` so you should see the data there or via one of its methods.

Look for a capture id, which has the same 17 alphanumeric format as an order id but is a different value. The capture id corresponds to the PayPal transaction id used for accounting purposes in PayPal.com details , reports, and email notifications to the receiver.

(The order id is only used during approval and there is no reason to store it permanently, it's only useful for debug purposes)

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,but the result object has only OrderResponse (order id and status ). if i can get transaction id will be good step .

Comment: How can I get the `id` from `CaptureOrderResult` object?